# Trying to use TkInter with Socat in Docker - Mac

Tags: python, docker, tkinter, socat, xquartz

Here's my steps..

Installing Socat and XQuartz

```
brew install socat
brew cask install xquartz
```

Opening XQuartz setting Socat Listener

```
open -a XQuartz
socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
```

Running Docker container with DISPLAY environmental variable

```
docker run -e DISPLAY=192.168.0.13:0 tkinter sh
```

Here's the error I'm receiving.

// Container

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "192.168.0.13:0"

// Socat

> socat[37688] E connect(8, LEN=2 AF=1 "", 2): Invalid argument

Any other IP address gives me a similar error but doesn't show up in Socat so I can assume my IP is correct.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to run a GUI app within docker? have you seen [this](https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/31/docker-for-mac-and-gui-applications/) method?

after you open Xquartz you have to allow connections from network clients. 
I know on linux you have to share your .x11 volume and enable xhost and it looks like on a mac you have to do the same:

```
ip=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')
xhost + $ip
docker run -d --name displayContainer -e DISPLAY=$ip:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix <yourRepo>/<yourImage>
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't help in my situation.